# How to write generic code to get time taken by a method execution in c#

Tags: c#

I need to log time taken by various methods , code blocks in my enterprise server application
I am using Stopwatch as of now , sample code what I've implemented is as below:

```
var sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();
DoSomething();
sw.Stop();
logManager.LogInformation(String.Format("Time taken by DoSomething function is {0} ms.", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds));
```

I am writing like this at many places in many .cs files, I just wanted to reduce this manual work by writing one common method or extension for measuring time taken. For this I am thinking to Wrap my actual method with the time measuring method like:

```
long elapsedMilliseconds = ExecuteAndGetTimeTaken(this.DoSomething());
```

Or generic extension methods like

```
long elapsedMilliseconds = this.DoSomething().GetTimeTaken();
```

It will be great if the method log the message with time taken too e.g.

```
long elapsedMilliseconds = ExecuteAndGetTimeTaken(this.DoSomething(),logManager,message);
```

How to write common class / method or extensions to solve the purpose?

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: @DanielA.White question added.

Comment: @ImranRizvi Probably because you still haven't asked a question.

Comment: @DanielKelley, I did but did not come, now i wrote again.

Comment: @DanielA.White can you please review your -1?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do:

```
void ExecuteAndMeasureTimeTaken(Action action, string message)
{
    if(action == null) throw new ArgumentNullException();
    else
    {
        var sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();

        action();

        sw.Stop(); 

        LogMessage(message , sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }
}
```

Call it like this:

```
logManager.ExecuteAndMeasureTimeTaken(() => GC.Collect(), "Time taken by GC after each Listning is {0} ms.");
```

Doest it really need a LogManager parameter?

If so, you may add this to your LogManager itself.

Comment: Not sure how you wanna deal with the logmanager there, i hope you still get the idea.

Comment: It looks great. yes , that would be great. I've edited your answer as per my requirement. I will try it

Comment: @ImranRizvi we both learned something here. I have troubles naming things, you helped me out :p

Answer (score 2):

I created once a short class, which can be used in a using statement. 
one other advantage is, that if an exception is thrown, also the time is measured

```
/// <summary>
/// Provides a easy to use timer. 
/// Usage
/// using(new DiagnosticTimer())
/// {
///     // do anything
/// }
/// </summary>
public class DiagnosticTimer : IDisposable
{
    public System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch StopWatch { get; protected set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }

    public DiagnosticTimer()
    {
        Message = "Diagnostic Timer at " + new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace().GetFrame(1).ToString();
        StopWatch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
        StopWatch.Start();
    }
    public DiagnosticTimer(string Message)
    {
        this.Message = Message;
        StopWatch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
        StopWatch.Start();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        StopWatch.Stop();
        System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(Message + StopWatch.Elapsed.ToString());
    }

}
```

Comment: if you want to measure a single function exectution time, you can just put `using(new DiagnosticTimer())` in advance

Comment: it sounds great!! similar to answer given by Csharpie , and offer good looking, dispose promising calling.

Comment: How can I get Elapsed time outside after dispose?

Comment: there is no way of accessing the object directly, as it already has been disposed. the only way i can imageine is using a static field and saving the elapsed value into that static field, or using a global logger object

Comment: In that case CSharpie's solution gives more flexibility. There are some senario in my project where I need elapsed time for calculation after dispose.

Comment: You could add an event that is fired in the Dispose, which has the Epelapsed time as a parameter.